# addchap but do not reset counters

Tags: koma-script, counters

In the following document, both figures are labeled **Figure 1.1**. How can I prevent the figure counter resetting after `\addchap`?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{XX}
\phantom{.}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\addchap{YY}
\phantom{.}
\begin{figure}
\caption{B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want the second caption to look like? The first number stands for the chapter number. But there is no chapter number here.

Comment: Figure 1.2 (as if it the `\addchap` didn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different command than `\addchap` which reset the counters:

```
\newcounter{superchapterfigure}
\newcounter{superchaptertable}
\newcounter{superchaptersection}

\newcommand{\addresetchap}[1]{%
    \setcounter{superchapterfigure}{\value{figure}}
    \setcounter{superchaptertable}{\value{table}}
    \setcounter{superchaptersection}{\value{section}}
\addchap{#1}
    \setcounter{figure}{\value{superchapterfigure}}
    \setcounter{table}{\value{superchaptertable}}
    \setcounter{section}{\value{superchaptersection}}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\addchap` uses the `\chapter` command but changes the counter `secnumdepth` locally to `\chapternumdepth-1` to get an unnumbered chapter with TOC and header entries. So I see no possibility to avoid the counter resetting only while using `\addchap`.

You could use  `\chapter*` command followed by `\addchaptertocentry` (TOC entry) and `\addchapmark` (header entry).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{XX}
\phantom{.}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\chapter*{YY}\addchaptertocentry{}{YY}\addchapmark{YY}
\phantom{.}
\begin{figure}
\caption{B}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```